# Trying to compare two arrays and reordering one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays, one is randomly generated string and the other is generated by pushing user inputs into it.

both start blank.

I need to compare the user-generated array to the original array for the length and the order and resort the user-generated array to match the original array. I've looked at several possibilities to compare them and it hasn't worked out for me so far.

Variables (declared above the function)

```
    var rightLtrsArr = [];
    var randWord;
    var randWordArr =[];

// step 1: set variables
// need variables for wins, losses, maxGuessCount, guessCount, wordsArr, wrongLtrsArr, rightLtrsArr,

var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var maxGuessCount = 10;
var guessCount = 0;
var words = ["evaluate", "leader", "glory", "thanks", "pit", "sign", "neighborhood", "twist", "beneficiary", "giant", "bargain", "analyst", "embark", "competition", "bench", "impress", "tick", 
            "elegant", "wing", "spring", "rider", "romantic", "confuse", "arrange", "critic", "quiet", "raise", "paradox", "inject", 
            "gallery", "scheme", "commerce", "museum", "computer", "fastidious", "impulse", "stand", "story", "pig", "oyster", "grim", 
            "speaker", "listen", "dense", "mass", "thin", "fat", "keys", "phone", "wallet", "money", "campaign",
            "mutter", "butterfly", "salmon", "occupation", "contempt", "landowner", "detector", "kidney", "faux", "require", "glass", "jug",
            "plastic", "overwhelm", "blackmail", "headquarters", "assignment", "competence"
        ];
var rightLtrsArr = [];
var randWord;
var randWordArr =[];


// START GAME FUNCTION
// _______________________________________________
function startGame() {
    // setting our win count/loss count box
    $('#winCountBox').html(wins);
    $('#lossCountBox').html(losses);

    // clearing the wrong guesses list box
    $('#wrongGuessList').empty();

    // disabling user input until a new word is called
    $('#userInput').attr('disabled', true);

    // clearing out guessCount box
    $('#guessesLeftBox').empty();

    // guesses alloted box
    $('#maxGuessCountBox').html(maxGuessCount);

    // clear wordbox
    $('#wordBox').empty();

}


// RESET GAME FUNCTION
// _______________________________________________

function resetGame() {

    // 2. resets win/loss record
    wins = 0;
    losses = 0;
    // 1. calls start game function
   startGame();
}

// GET WORD FUNCTION
// _______________________________________________
function getWord() {

    // clears the randWordArr of any previous words
    randWordArr.length = 0;

    // 2. generates a new word & pushes it into the randWordArray
    randWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    var randWordLngth = randWord.length;
    randWordArr.push(randWord);
    console.log(randWordArr);
    console.log('The random word is ' + randWord + " and the length is " + randWordLngth);

    // 3. generates the blank spaces for the word
    var tempSpace = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < randWordLngth; i++) {
        tempSpace = tempSpace + ' ___ ';
    }

    $('#wordBox').html(tempSpace);

    // 4. resets maxGuessCount & guessCount
    guessCount = 0;
    maxGuessCount = 10;
    $('#guessesLeftBox').html(maxGuessCount);

    // 5. empties the list of wrongly guessed characters in html box
    $('#wrongGuessList').empty();

    // 6. allowing user to enter data into input field
    $('#userInput').attr('disabled', false);
}



// START GAME CLICK EVENT
// _______________________________________________
$('#startGameBTN').on('click', function(){
    startGame();
});



// NEW WORD CLICK EVENT
// _______________________________________________

$('#getWordBTN').on('click', function(){
    getWord();
});



// RESET GAME CLICK EVENT
// _______________________________________________

$('#resetGameBTN').on('click', function(){
    resetGame();
});



// GAMEPLAY FUNCTIONALITY
// _______________________________________________

// 1. button click event
$('#inputBTN').on('click', function(){

    // startGame();

    // 2. get user input
    var userInput = $('input').val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(userInput);
    $('input').val('');

    // 3. verify if user entered a single character/if not, throw err msg
    function isSingleInput (userInput){
        if(userInput.length === 1) {

            // 4. verify the char is a string and not a number/if not, throw err msg
            function isNumber(x) {
                if (isNaN(x)) {

                // 5. check if input character is in the randWordArr
                    var isCharInWord = randWord.indexOf(userInput);

                    // 6. if char is in the hidden word: print all instances of that letter to the screen surrounded by blank spaces
                    if (isCharInWord >= 0) {

                        rightLtrsArr.push(userInput);

                        // for (var i = 0; i < randWordArr; i++) {
                        //     console.log(randWordArr[i]);
                        // }

                        // var myNewArr = randWordArr.split();
                        // console.log(myNewArr);

                        // console.log(rightLtrsArr + " : " + rightLtrsArr.length);

                        // console.log(randWordArr.length);

                        // if (rightLtrsArr.length === randWordArr.length) {
                        //     console.log('the arrays are equal');
                        // } else {
                        //     console.log('they are not equal');
                        // }

                        // function arraysAreIdentical(rightLtrsArr, randWordArr){

                        //     if(rightLtrsArr.length != randWordArr) {
                        //         console.log("not equal");
                        //     }

                        //     // if (rightLtrsArr.length !== randWordArr.length) return false;
                        //     // for (var i = 0, len = rightLtrsArr.length; i < len; i++){
                        //     //     if (rightLtrsArr[i] !== randWordArr[i]){
                        //     //         console.log("false");
                        //     //     }
                        //     // }
                        //     // console.log("true"); 
                        // }

                        // arraysAreIdentical(randWordArr, randWordArr);

                        // for (var i = 0; i < rightLtrsArr.length; i++) {
                        //     $('#wordBox').html(rightLtrsArr[i]);
                        // }

                    } else {
                        console.log("nope, can't find it");

                    // 7. if char is not in the hidden word: create an array with chars that aren't in the word, print to screen as list, 
                    //      update guess count variable, update guesscount html output to screen

                        $('#wrongGuessList').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + userInput + "</li>");
                        guessCount ++;
                        $('#guessesLeftBox').html(guessCount + " / " + maxGuessCount);

                    // 8. if user is out of guesses, update lost record, alert user, disable input 
                        if (guessCount === maxGuessCount) {
                            alert("Marty McFly gets shafted :(");
                            losses ++;
                            $('#lossCountBox').html(losses);
                            $('input').attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                    }


                } else {
                    alert("What is we're looking for a letter in the English alphabet for 200, Alex.");
                }
            }

            isNumber(userInput)

        } else if (userInput.length > 1) {
            // if not a single char, prompt user for single char
            alert("Overzealous much? Take it one character at a time. Please and thank you.");
            // need to break out of the function here

        } else {
            console.log("the length is less than one");
        }
    }

    isSingleInput(userInput);


});
```

Comment: What is `randWord` finally? Where and how does `userInput` come from? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: updated with full js. randWord is a string pulled via the math method from an array of words. UserInput is a single character as a string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. If the random array is [1,2,3,4,5] and user array is [4,2] you want the user array to be sorted as [2,4] because that is the order that 2 and 4 are in the random array? Is it guaranteed that items in user array are in random array? it's nice you posted 230 lines for completeness sake but no way anyone is actually going to read that when you can express your problem with a lot less. Can you please try to explain clearly what it is you want and then put minimal amount of code demonstrating how it is you tried it.

Comment: sure. words var is an array full of words. randWord grabs a random word from that array and stores it in its own array. randWordArr. The user is supposed to guess what the word is via an input one character at a time (i.e. 's'). The input val is saved (userInput) as a string. I run a check to see if the user input char is in the randWordArr. if it is, I save that correctly guessed word in a new array - rightLtrsArr. Then I need to compare the randWordArr to rightLtrsArr. Check their length and order. Then arrange rightLtrsArr in the same character order as randWordArr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it works now! See the snippet below.

```js
var randWord, guessWord, userInput = '',
  wins = 0,
  losses = 0,
  maxGuessCount = 10,
  guessCount = 0,
  words = ["evaluate", "leader", "glory", "thanks", "pit", "sign", "neighborhood", "twist", "beneficiary", "giant", "bargain", "analyst", "embark", "competition", "bench", "impress", "tick", "elegant", "wing", "spring", "rider", "romantic", "confuse", "arrange", "critic", "quiet", "raise", "paradox", "inject", "gallery", "scheme", "commerce", "museum", "computer", "fastidious", "impulse", "stand", "story", "pig", "oyster", "grim", "speaker", "listen", "dense", "mass", "thin", "fat", "keys", "phone", "wallet", "money", "campaign", "mutter", "butterfly", "salmon", "occupation", "contempt", "landowner", "detector", "kidney", "faux", "require", "glass", "jug", "plastic", "overwhelm", "blackmail", "headquarters", "assignment", "competence"];

startGame();

// START GAME FUNCTION
// _______________________________________________
function startGame() {
  // setting our win count/loss count box
  $('#winCountBox').html(wins);
  $('#lossCountBox').html(losses);
  $('#maxGuessCountBox').html(maxGuessCount);

  // disabling user input until a new word is called
  $('#userInput').attr('disabled', true);

  // clear wordbox
  $('#wordBox').empty();
  getWord();

}

function showLetters() {
  var tempSpace = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < guessWord.length; i++) {
    tempSpace.push(userInput === randWord[i] ? userInput : guessWord[i]);
  }
  guessWord = tempSpace.join('');
  $('#wordBox').html(tempSpace.join(' '));
  if (guessWord === randWord) {
    alert('You win!');
    ++wins;
    startGame();
  }
  return !!(guessWord.indexOf(userInput) + 1);
}

// GET WORD FUNCTION
// _______________________________________________
function getWord() {
  userInput = '';
  randWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  guessWord = '_'.repeat(randWord.length);
  console.log('The random word is ' + randWord + " and the length is " + randWord.length);

  showLetters();

  // 4. resets maxGuessCount & guessCount
  guessCount = 0;
  $('#guessesLeftBox').html(maxGuessCount);

  // 5. empties the list of wrongly guessed characters in html box
  $('#wrongGuessList').empty();

  // 6. allowing user to enter data into input field
  $('#userInput').attr('disabled', false);
}



// START GAME CLICK EVENT
// _______________________________________________
$('#startGameBTN').on('click', function() {
  startGame();
});

// RESEST GAME CLICK EVENT
// _______________________________________________
$('#resetGameBTN').on('click', function() {
  wins = 0;
  losses = 0;
  startGame();
});

// GAMEPLAY FUNCTIONALITY
// _______________________________________________

// 1. button click event
$('#inputBTN').on('click', function() {

  // 2. get user input
  userInput = $('input').focus().val().trim().toLowerCase();

  if (!userInput) return alert("the length is less than one");
  if (userInput.length > 1) return alert("One character at a time, please and thank you.");
  if (/[^a-z]/.test(userInput)) return alert("Enter an English alphabet letter please.");

  $('input').val('');

  // 5. check if input character is in the randWordArr
  if (!showLetters()) {
    console.log("nope, can't find it");

    $('#wrongGuessList').append(" " + userInput);
    $('#guessesLeftBox').html(maxGuessCount - ++guessCount);

    if (guessCount === maxGuessCount) {
      alert("Marty McFly gets shafted :(");
      ++losses;
      startGame();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.counter {
  display: inline-block;margin: 20px 40px
}

.counter span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: solid 1px;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="counter">
  Count:<br> Wins: <span id="winCountBox"></span> Losses: <span id="lossCountBox"></span>
</div>

<div class="counter">
  Guesses: <b id="wrongGuessList"></b><br> Left: <span id="guessesLeftBox"></span> from <span id="maxGuessCountBox"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="startGameBTN">Start</button>
  <button id="resetGameBTN">Reset</button>
  <!-- <button id="getWordBTN">Word</button> -->
</div>

<h1 id="wordBox"></h1>

<div class="counter">
  <input id="userInput" maxlength="1" pattern="[a-z]"> <button id="inputBTN">Try Letter</button>
</div>
```